# Haskell input - how to read x number of inputs from stdin

Tags: haskell, io, user-input

The user will enter a number of cases, the length of the case, and then the case. The number of cases varies each time. Example of user input:

```
2
4
"four"
3
"the"
```

I need to do something to each of the cases, but how do I get the execute the do loop to match the number of cases?

This is what I have so far:

```
main = do
    numOfCases <- getInteger
    caseLength <- getInteger
    case <- getLine
    putStrLn $ doSomething case
    --how do I call the loop exactly once more, but this time without the numOfCases?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `replicateM_`, which repeats an action a given number of times.  You import it from `Control.Monad`:

```
replicateM_ :: (Monad m) => Int -> m a -> m ()
```

So you would use it like this:

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM_)

main = do
    numOfCases <- readLn
    replicateM_ numOfCases $ do
        caseLength <- readLn
        str <- getLine
        ... -- do other stuff
```